# extjs retrieving config info for instantiated object?

Tags: extjs

I need to build a PropertyManager for e.g. a tab on a tab bar.... tab1.config; and tab1.configMap; are empty objects at runtime. I also tried Ext.TabPanel.configMap; and Ext.TabPanel.config; which come back as undefined. Is there a way of getting this info? Architect does this exact same thing to display its PropertyManager to set properties. tia.

... I am thinking that maybe the solution is to create each object with a config: of all the properties to be inspected so that they can be reached.

Comment: Some config properties are present in prototype, but not all. Probably most realyable method would be to extract that info from debug version of Ext JS library by searching for '@cfg' in comments. Once done, you can cache this info somewhere to access it faster.